# Plot graph: count x hour in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataset with the columns `StartTime` (e.g. `16:32:11`) and `Date`, `ID`, and so on.

I want to plot a graph with on the x-axis the hour `(00:00:00, 01:00:00 .. 23:00:00)` and on the y-axis the count of the aggregated entries that have a `StartTime` that falls in that hour.

How to plot this graph? First do I need to covert the `StartTime` with `as.POSIXct(strptime)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lubridate package to extract hours from the string then plot a histogram:

```
# simulate data
library(lubridate)
set.seed(123)

n <- 1000 # number of rows/observations

event_time <- seconds_to_period(seconds(seq(0, 24 * 60 * 60 - 1)))
start_time <- sample(sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', hour(event_time), minute(event_time), second(event_time)), 
                     size = n, 
                     replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(
  start_time, 
  id = 1:n, 
  start_date = sample(seq(dmy("01/01/2017"), dmy("01/01/2018"), 1), n, replace = TRUE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# plot histogram of time distribution of events
head(df)

#   start_time id start_date hour
# 1   06:54:06  1 2017-04-11    6
# 2   18:55:09  2 2017-08-06   18
# 3   09:48:55  3 2017-02-28    9
# 4   21:11:32  4 2017-11-09   21
# 5   22:34:16  5 2017-11-07   22
# 6   01:05:36  6 2017-06-24    1

df$hour <- hour(hms(df$start_time))
hist(df$hour, breaks = 24, xlim = c(0, 25))
```

Output:
[image: Distribution of events]